# Is it possible to access UI elements from other than the Main thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have read from many tutorials and online resources that we can not access UI elements from other than the main threads. Where, we can access UI elements using handlers, runOnUiThread or AsyncTask. But, here I have a question regarding this from the following piece of code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressBar progress;
TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progreeBar);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading);
    Thread thread = new Thread(new myThread());
    thread.start();

}

public class myThread implements  Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        progress.setProgress(50);
        text.setText("counter: "+50);
    }
}
}
```

[image: Code Output]

In the above code, I can access the UI elements from another thread without using any handler, runOnUiThread, or AsyncTask. I am curious that why I have no error on accessing UI elements from outside the Main Thread?

Comment: You can access the UI elements.  They just may not update the way you want.

Comment: I didn't find anything except that you **should not** work with UI on background thread.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you. Problem is I am still learning and building my concepts. Here, I am confused that why I can access the UI from Main Thread without having having any runOnUiThread, Handlers, or AysncTasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can update UI from other thread but you should avoid it. Because as per Android documentation

> Andoid UI toolkit is not [thread-safe](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads)